# How to find which application is used ctrl+y?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce, i3-wm

my sistem is xubuntu 22.04 with i3wm window manager.
Now, when i press ctrl+y, the cursor has transformed into a cross and requires you to select an area to copy to the clipboard, it will be an image to insert to skype, for example.

For i3wm, in ~/.config/i3wm/config is nothign with ctrl+y.
And in my system too.

I think is for old installed application.

But i can't find it.

Thanks.

Comment: If the same as standard Ubuntu 22.04 open `Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts` and in the search box, enter the shortcut as `ctrl+y` and see what it returns, You could also use `Windows` option (which indicates the number modified.